# tiny mce not working properly in google chrome

Tags: tinymce, google-chrome

I have four textareas in my form. TinyMce editor applies to only first row of the textarea, remaining rows for textareas dont get editor in google chrome. It works fine in firefox instead.

Comment: any code for this? or shall we just guess?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing the code, but I'm going to go ahead guess that you are referencing your multiple textareas using the same ID.  IDs must be unique - so give them each  their own individual ID and then attach the editor with four separate calls, or reference them by class instead.

Or attach some code for us to take a look at.